# Pandas Dataframe filter and For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with many columns. I am trying to filter one of those columns ('Region') and create a separate dataframe based on each of those 4 regions in the ''Region' column. And then run a large block of code that contains a bunch of calculations on each of those 4 separate dataframes without having to rewrite the large block of code 4 separate times.

I know i can use an .isin function for the column filtering and do this for my 4 regions (US, EM, Europe, Asia):

```
US = df[df['Region'].isin('US')]
EM = df[df['Region'].isin('EM')]
Europe = df[df['Region'].isin('Europe')]
Asia = df[df['Region'].isin('Asia')]
```

And then run my block of code on the 4 new dataframes. But i would be executing my large block of calculation code 4 separate times and it is just too messy. How can i do this in a loop so i only have to write my large block of code one time? If there is another function i can use to do this besides a for loop that would be awesome as well. Appreciate any help- trying to learn.

Dummy Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b':['cats','dogs','birds','pianos','elephant','dinos'], 'Region' : ['EM', 'US', 'US', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'Asia']})
```

Comment: Can you provide some clue on this "large block of code"?

Comment: Why do you need to split the `DataFrame`? If the calculations for each region are all similar, then you can either use `np.select` or a dictionary to map the regions to region-specific values for each calculation. But without knowing *what* you need to do, it's hard to provide more guidance.

Answer (score 6):

Just iterate a `groupby` object:

```
dfs = {}
for region, df_region in df.groupby('Region'):
    # do something to df_region
    # ...
    # then store in dictionary
    dfs[region] = df_region
```

Then access individual dataframes via `dfs['US']`, `dfs['Asia']`, etc.

You can, of course, tailor your operation to be dependent on `region`, but this is not necessary. Each `df_region` represents a dataframe filtered by `df[df['Region'] == region]`.

Comment: `df.groupby('Region').apply(some_function)` ?

Comment: @d_kennetz, Depends on the operations. But yes, potentially.

Comment: @d_kennetz I think just mentioned `groupby` is good enough , since we do not know the function he want to apply

Comment: the large block of code i want to run is basically just a few pivot tables that i stack together to create one giant dataframe

Comment: @spacedinosaur10 then you can run it pivot table with you original df , since pivot is another layout of groupby check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: Agree with @W-B, you are asking for a solution to the *wrong* problem.

Comment: Yeah i figured i was looking at it wrong. thanks for the help. I I am kind of confused by the output though.. Below is an example of my pivot (imagine Roll, animal and year are all columns in df. I want it to run through my code produce 4 different pivots, one for each region, so that i can .concat them on top of each other. dfs = {}
for region, df_region in df.groupby('Region'):
    pivot = df[df['Roll'].isin(Analyst) & df['Animal'].isin(cat) & df['Year'].isin(2010)]

dfs[region] = df_region

Comment: @spacedinosaur10, I can't read code in comments. I suggest you write a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a **[mcve]** (including input & desired output).

Comment: created a separate question that is a bit easier to understand- thanks- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888636/create-separate-dataframes-by-iterate-a-groupby-object